# Can counter value be not in sorted order?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I am trying to understand node.js streams. Since the write method on the writer object method is asynchronous, can counter value be out of order?

```
const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve("modules", "streams", "hello"));
writer.on("finish", () => console.log("Finished Writing"));
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) writer.write(`Hello:${i}`); // this is async, according to me
writer.end();
console.log("Hello");

Outputs: 
Hello
Finished Writing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the counter won't be out of order.  Streams insert items into the outgoing buffer as you call `.write()` and all your writes are called in order.

But, a loop like this needs flow control on the `writer.write()` because if it returns `false`, then you can't write any more until the `drain` event on the stream indicates that there is more room for writing.  See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) in the doc for more info.

The `write.write()` function is asynchronous, but because of buffering and other events on the stream you don't necessarily have to register a complete callback for every write.  The `write.write()` puts data in the outbound buffer and returns `true` immediately when the data has been successfully buffered or it returns `false` immediately if there's no room in the buffer.

The actual write to the file stream is indeed asynchronous and occurs largely out of your view.  Errors from the asynchronous part are communicated via the `error` event on the stream and, as you're already doing, completion of the stream is also communicated via an event.

The reason you get `Finished Writing` after `Hello` is because of the asynchronous writing behind the scenes.  Your `for` loop sets off the writes, but they are not yet complete when the `for` loop is done.  They finish some time later (when you see the `finish` event).

Comment: I am not getting error while writing, although writer.write() returning false.Why?

Comment: @RajatAggarwal - If you read the [doc for `.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback), it is all explained there.  It will try to avoid an error, by consuming larger amounts of memory, causing excess GC and perhaps even aborting.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal - If you know you're not going to be writing a lot of data, you can get away without paying attention to the boolean return value and the drain event.

Comment: I was just learning about streams in node, got to know more about them, thanks.